# Different results when using ANSI and non-ANSI Join syntax

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help from an Oracle SQL expert because I can't find a solution to this problem anywhere.

We have a query in ANSI that combines three tables. It gives 106 rows:

```
select *
from employees e
right join departments d on e.department_id = d.department_id
right join jobs j on e.job_id = j.job_id;
```

But if we convert it to non-ANSI syntax, it does some kind of a cross join (*departments* table with *jobs* table?), and it outputs 600 rows:

```
select *
from employees e, departments d, jobs j
where e.department_id(+) = d.department_id
and e.job_id(+) = j.job_id;
```

Why is this happening? I know how to fix it, but can someone tell me what logic is behind it? Because with regular JOIN, first the *employees* table is joined with *departments*, and only then the result of this join is joined with *jobs*. But with non-ANSI it doesn't work.

Could someone please tell me (step by step) how the second non ANSI query is executed?

```
This is the default HR schema from Oracle:
    --------------- -------- ------------ 
    Employees (107 rows):
    
    EMPLOYEE_ID          
    FIRST_NAME             
    LAST_NAME              
    EMAIL                          
    PHONE_NUMBER            
    HIRE_DATE      
    JOB_ID         
    SALARY                
    COMMISSION_PCT          
    MANAGER_ID             
    DEPARTMENT_ID           
    -------------- -------- ------------ 
    Departments (27 rows):
    
    DEPARTMENT_ID  
    DEPARTMENT_NAME 
    MANAGER_ID              
    LOCATION_ID             
    -------------- -------- ------------ 
    Jobs (19 rows):
    
    JOB_ID     
    JOB_TITLE  
    MIN_SALARY          
    MAX_SALARY         
    --------------- -------- ------------
```

Comment: Did you check query plans for both of them?

Comment: You don't have a join between `d` and `j`. That will definitely produce a cross product in the native syntax. It does the first outer join, then the second, then joins the two together, which will produce a many-to-many between them. Apparently compounded RIGHT JOINs work differently.

Answer (score 3):

The first query does this:

1. Join `departments` and `employees` using`departments` as the leading (left) table.
2. Join `jobs` and result of step 2 using`jobs` as a leading (left) table.

The second query does this:

1. Do a cross product of two tables.
2. Join results of step 1 to `employees` table with results of step 1 as a leading (left) table.

The second query behaves this way because:

- Order of tables in the `from` clause doesn't mean anything.
- According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6):

> **CROSS**
>
> The `CROSS` keyword indicates that a cross join is being performed. A cross join produces the cross-product of two relations **and is essentially the same as the comma-delimited Oracle Database notation**.

- `JOIN` paragraph also describes this:

> To write a query that performs an outer join of tables A and B and returns all rows from B (a right outer join), use the `RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN` syntax in the `FROM` clause, or apply the outer join operator (`+`) to **all columns of A in the join condition in the `WHERE` clause**.

Your `where` condition does'n have left-joined column from `departments` table.

To obtain the same result you have to put `departments d, employees e` join into the subquery:

```
select *
from (
  select e.*
  from employees e, departments d
  where d.department_id = e.department_id(+)
) ed, jobs j
where 1 = 1
and j.job_id = ed.job_id(+)
```

```
select * from dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format => '+PREDICATE')
```

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT 
:-----------------
SQL_ID  268fcvwcc46dz, child number 0 
------------------------------------- 
select * from (   select e.*   from employees e, departments d   where  
d.department_id = e.department_id(+) ) ed, jobs j where 1 = 1 and  
j.job_id = ed.job_id(+) 

Plan hash value: 54029785 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
| Id  | Operation            | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |             |       |       |     6 (100)|          | 
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN OUTER     |             |     1 |   185 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | JOBS        |     1 |    52 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|   3 |   VIEW               |             |     1 |   133 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|*  4 |    HASH JOIN OUTER   |             |     1 |   146 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| DEPARTMENTS |     1 |    13 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| EMPLOYEES   |     1 |   133 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - access("J"."JOB_ID"="ED"."JOB_ID")
   4 - access("D"."DEPARTMENT_ID"="E"."DEPARTMENT_ID")
 
Note
-----
   - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iFOp29r5)